# Plot Non-linear Plot for Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, least-squares

```
y<-c(0.0100,2.3984,11.0256,4.0272,0.2408,0.0200);
x<-c(1,3,5,7,9,11);
d<-data.frame(x,y)
myLm<-lm(x~y**2,data=d)
plot(d)
lines(x,lm(y ~ I(log(x)) + x,data=d)$fitted.values)
lines(x,lm(y ~ I(x**2) + x,data=d)$fitted.values) % not quite right, smooth plz
```

It should be smooth plot, something wrong.

[image]

**Helper questions**

1. [What algorithm is used in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/what-algorithm-is-used-in-linear-regression)
2. [Explain least squares plotting with Ones -matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87965/explain-least-squares-plotting-with-ones-matrix)

Comment: What does "nevertheless of the points or compliance" mean?

Comment: He edited the posts numerous times, changing his word etc.  AndresT and I tried to help last night but, well, the terms of the question kept shifting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `predict` in order to interpolate the predictions between the fitted points.

```
d <- data.frame(x=seq(1,11,by=2),
                y=c(0.0100,2.3984,11.0256,4.0272,0.2408,0.0200))
lm1 <-lm(y ~ log(x)+x, data=d)
lm2 <-lm(y ~ I(x^2)+x, data=d)
xvec <- seq(0,12,length=101)
plot(d)
lines(xvec,predict(lm1,data.frame(x=xvec)))
lines(xvec,predict(lm2,data.frame(x=xvec)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, after he finally edited in that all he wants is a parabola, the predict() over a sequence of x-axis point is the correct answer. Note how his first fit still models y as a function of y. Oh well.  I'm sure he'll update that now that I mention.

Comment: what could i do if i have multiple variables, rather than only one independent variable.

Comment: @FrankWANG: you should probably post a new question, referencing this one, and giving appropriate detail (e.g. a reproducible question: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ).  Short answer, you have to decide between (1) producing a surface plot; (2) drawing one or more predicted lines (or subplots) with all but one of the predictors held at a specified value.

Answer (score 6):

The mandatory ggplot2 method:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,y)+stat_smooth(method="lm", formula="y~poly(x,2)", se=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have many plots in the same picture? This is apparently some different environment so I cannot use the style `plot(1:10,1:10); lines(1:10, 1:10*2)` etc.

Comment: Yes, just add extra layers or aesthetics, eg: `dfr <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,2),y=c(1:10,(1:10)^2),type=c(rep("linear",10),rep("squared",10))); qplot(x,y,data=dfr,geom="line",colour=type)`

Comment: Also ggplot2 uses the grid graphics system rather than the base one so the commands and paradigms are different, see http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/

Answer (score 3):

something like:

```
 plot(d)    
 abline(lm(x~y**2,data=d), col="black")
```

will make it (if linear, as was implied by the way the question was asked first)

For what you are looking for I think:

```
  lines(smooth.spline(x, y))
```

May work as hinted by Dirk.

Comment: Maybe not quite as he is fitting a linear model where his regressor is squared.

Answer (score 2):

You should spend some time with the 'Appendix A: A sample session' of the 'An Introduction R' manual that came with your program.  But here is a start

```
R> y<-c(0.0100,2.3984,11.0256,4.0272,0.2408,0.0200);
R> x<-c(1,3,5,7,9,11);
R> d<-data.frame(x,y)
R> myLm<-lm(x~y**2,data=d)
R> myLm

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y^2, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            y  
      6.434       -0.147
```

and we can plot this as (where I now corrected for your unusual inversion of the roles of `x` and `y`):

```
R> plot(d)
R> lines(d$y,fitted(myLm))
```

[image]

Comment: ...err quadratic regression, this is linear.

Comment: That's just it: you are fitting a *linear model* over a nonlinear transformation of your variables.   You could create `x2 <- x^2` and then regress `y ~ x2` and plot that in `(y,x2)` space.  If you want a *nonlinear regression* you need a different function such as `nls()`.  Or splines. Or additive models. Or, or, or ...

Comment: look now the question, is it now clear. No fuzzy sentences, only one clear picture -- got what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you be a little more rude to people who you give free lessons?